# extract string in double quotation(there are pair double quotations at string)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

i have a string

```
$sting=
'   [
        type="user"
        name="ali"
        key="#$WRE"

        //problem
        address="{
            "type":"hellow"
        }"
    ]';
```

and i extract data with key=value format

```
for (;;) {
if(!preg_match('~([A-Za-z0-9]+)\=\"([^\"]*)\"~m', $string,$match)){
    break;
}
$string=str_replace($match[0], '', $string);

$dataArray[$match[1]]=$match[2];
}

echo "<br><pre>";
print_r($dataArray);
echo "<br></pre>";
```

but output is

```html
<br><pre>Array
(
    [type] = user
    [name] = ali
    [key] = #$WRE
    [address] = {
    
)
<br></pre>
```

According to [address]
(im not good at english For this reason, there may be errors in the sentences)

please help me

Comment: are you like trying to parse json by yourself?

Comment: @Iceman That's not standard JSON. The address field shouldn't have the *surrounding* `"` if it was JSON. @Mortaza Is that really what your input look like?

Comment: @ClasG I was aware of that, but was confirming whether it was a paste gone wrong!

Comment: input data is not a valid json. so please post the correct data

Comment: its not a json string!  Imagine this is a plain text

Comment: The problem is that you search only on single-lines, so it doesn't work. If you do a multiple-line regex, it will search and stop at the first `"` so that doesn't solve the problem. I'll search for a solution. (p.s. you say you're not english what's your language ?)

Comment: ---it will search and stop at the first " so that doesn't solve the problem -- i know it But what's the solution؟

Comment: There is a way for extract data with key=value format without editing string?

Comment: @ClasG no,but It is possible

Comment: Yes, it is possible - [`/(\w+)=(?|"\{(.*?)}"|"(.*?)")$/ms`](https://regex101.com/r/eE9nO8/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, it does not work but Helped me to find the correct pattern ,,,this is correct pattern '/(\w+)=(?|"({.*?})"|"(.*?)")/ms'

Comment: That just means you want the braces to be part of the capture group, and my regex is correct. I will post with explanation then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Send a description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex like

```
'/(\w+)\s*=\s*"(.*?)"\s*(?=$|\w+\s*=)/ms'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eE9nO8/19)

**Pattern details**:

- The `/s` is a DOTALL modifier  that makes the `.` match any symbol including a newline
- The `/m` modifier makes `$` match the end of the line
- `(\w+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more alphanumeric or underscore characters
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `=` - an equal sign
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `"(.*?)"` - a double quote, zero or more any chars other than a newline as few as possible up to the first double quote and this quote as well (Group 2 is what is captured in between double quotes)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?=$|\w+\s*=)` -a positive lookahead requiring  the end of string to appear right after the current position or one or more alphanumeric followed with zero or more whitespaces and an equal sign.

Comment: This is cleaner now, but is not optimized.